# I am getting a wrong answer for this problem:Hackerrank

Tags: python, counter

Raghu is a shoe shop owner. His shop has X number of shoes.
He has a list containing the size of each shoe he has in his shop.
There are n number of customers who are willing to pay y

amount of money only if they get the shoe of their desired size.

Your task is to compute how much money
earned.

I know this question may seem useless for all you developers.But I am beginner in programming as well as python. So,please help me with this.I have tried many times,but the only answer I could get is 0.Here is my solution:

```
from collections import Counter
numshoes=int(input())
shoes=Counter(map(int,input().split()))
numcust=int(input())
income=0
for i in range(numcust):
    size,price=input().split()
    if(shoes[size]>0):
        income+=price
        shoes[size]-=1
    else:
        pass
print(income)
```

Input:

```
10

2 3 4 5 6 8 7 6 5 18

6

6 55

6 45

6 55

4 40

18 60

10 50
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
0
```

Expected Output

```
200
```

This is the output I get.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. You should be up front about homework questions, it might be helpful if you read the [guidelines on asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/39277)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`size` and `price` are strings. Cast them to ints before adding to income, like you do with `shoes`.

(As a word of advice, I recommend solving Hackerrank problems yourself because its purpose is to be a challenge.)